# Weird behavior of vsprintf

Tags: c

I have been pulling my hair out because of this 1 line of code.
If I don't dynamically allocate memory for the extra (by just having char extra[*cur_size+1];), vsprintf got stuck.

```
char *append(char *str, int *cur_size, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args) + strlen(str);
    if (len > *cur_size) {
        //alloc more memory
        *cur_size = len * sizeof (char) << 1;
        char *extra = malloc(*cur_size+1);
        // char extra[*cur_size+1]; will cause problem
        strcpy(extra, str);
        str = extra;
    }
    vsprintf(eos(str), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    LOGE("len = %d, cur_size = %d", len, *cur_size);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `<<` for multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use:

```
char extra[*cur_size + 1];
```

the array will be out of scope at the next `}`, meaning `str` will be a dangling pointer. When you use `malloc()` the memory outlives the scope.

Answer (score 2):

The array goes out of scope and becomes invalid to access through the aliased pointer `str`, which is why that solution won't work.

Your actual solution is broken too, though: it leaks the memory passed in by the caller in `str`, since that pointer just gets overwritten with the newly allocated memory `extra`.

If your function is expecting a dynamically allocated pointer in `str`, you should `free()` it before overwriting the pointer with `extra`. You might also want to look at `realloc()`, if so remember that the return value of `realloc()` might be a *new* pointer, so keep your current solution where `str` is returned by the function.